# Is there a way to check whether an SQL Server database has an active BEGIN CONVERSATION TIMER?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, service-broker

I'm using the messaging timer feature to schedule asynchronous procedure executions and all seems to be going well but I only tested it for a short time range (setting the timeout to a few hours).

I decided upon this feature because the timer functionality is supposed to be entirely contained "within" single database scope/context (as opposed to depend on the server instance). As a consequence the timer should not be interfered by server restarts, database restoration from backup (provided the backup has been done after the timer setup) etc. If it actually works that way in practice than I'll be really glad but it seems too beautiful to be true so I'd like to be able to check up on the timer. Maybe see how long 'till it fires even.

Is there a query I can run, maybe on the sys.objects table, that enables this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used this feature myself, but the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176082.aspx) says that `sys.conversation_endpoints.dialog_timer` is "The time at which the conversation timer for this dialog sends a DialogTimer message", which I think is what you're looking for.